# Read lines from text file and store it in array

Tags: arrays, bash

So i need to read all the lines from a text file(as an argument when i call the script) which contains numbers in this form(1 new line not 2):
num1:num2

num3:num4 etc

I use this command block:

```
while IFS= read line 
do
    IFS=':' read -r -a X <<< "$line" 
done < "$1"
```

to read the lines and numbers and store it into array X but the array goes only to position 0 and 1 and when it changes line it just write the new number(eg num3) where the old number was(eg num1 in pos 0)

Any solution to this?

Comment: Insert before your code `array=()` and before `done` insert `array+=( "${X[@]}" )` to append array `X` to array `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash. Replace all `:` with line break and use `mapfile` to fill array x.

```
mapfile -t x < <(tr ':' '\n' < file)
declare -p x
```

Output:

```
declare -a x='([0]="num1" [1]="num2" [2]="num3" [3]="num4")'
```

---

See: `help mapfile`

Comment: And what if i want to store the first number in one array and the second in a different array Y in each line

Comment: I recommend that you ask a new question (no comment) about this.